# .Net development on vista or XP

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, iis, windows-vista

I am wondering if it is better to develop .Net 2010 web application on XP as compare to Vista? I have developed many .Net applications on XP without any problem and personaly like XP over vista. Now i have started a new job and we are all mainly using Vista Ultimate 32 bit.

> **Are there any known issues with vista for VS2010 development?**

Application will be published on Window Server 2003 or 2008 so my main concern is developing and running application localy.

> **Also, is Visual Source Safe 6.0 Compatiable with Vista?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have some difficulty since XP is only 32 bit (unless you've got the 64-bit edition which is a little flakey re: drivers).

Also, certain features like XNA Game Studio, Windows Phone 7 development, DirectX 11, etc... just aren't supported on an XP development environment.

You may also hit issues with regards to integrating with the Azure cloud platform as it has some dependencies that don't work fully on XP.

That said, if you're only going for a simple Winforms/Console app/ASP.Net site, you probably won't ever notice the difference

Oh and .Net 4.5 [isn't supported on XP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As an aside, please DO NOT USE visual source safe - it's truly awful. It doesn't guarantee consistency, has no concept of branching and merging, doesn't allow multiple users to work on the same files and is generally unreliable (not to mention the fact that it relies on every client playing nicely and a single malicious user can drop the entire data store since it's really just a windows share with some files, not an actual server). See this article: [Visual SourceSafe Version Control: Unsafe at any Speed?](http://www.developsense.com/testing/VSSDefects.html) for more details.

You should use TFS or an open source alternative (I've also played with SVN and used AnkhSVN to integrate into VS - Not perfect but pretty good). If you want to use TFS but don't have the servers/experience to set up a server yourself, There's a (currently free) beta being run by microsoft at [tfspreview.com](http://tfspreview.com) which integrates right into VS 2010 SP1 and later and provides all the same functionality as well as a whole slew of other features like bug/workitem tracking, analytics, etc...

Comment: is Visual Source Safe 6 compatiable with vista?

Comment: Visual Source Safe is no longer supported by MS. You need to pay for support for it now. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ukmsdn/archive/2011/01/04/end-of-support-for-visual-sourcesafe.aspx

Comment: See my edit for why not to use VSS and bear in mind that was written in 2003.

Comment: we are using VS2010 Professional and don't have a license for TFS. I am not sure if i do need to use Version control bcz i am the only one developer designing softwares in the company.

Comment: It's always a good idea to use source control. Get yourself SVN.

Comment: @user1263981 As I said, the TFSPreview site is free but I can understand that you may prefer to go with SVN or others. I would strongly recommend you DO use source control - It's not only useful for collaborating but for undoing your own mistakes (When you realise something you changed yesterday broke everything, how do you go back?) also, it allows you to "shelve" ie put one incomplete piece of work aside, get back to a stable build, do a different fix, then get back your shelved work - so you can multitask more easily

Comment: I've worked in huge teams, small teams and as a solo developer and now I won't start writing code until I've got source control set up - It always saves time in the long run and has helped avoid some big cockups

Comment: TortoiseSVN integrates SVN with the windows explorer, AnkhSVN integrates with the VS IDE - I actually had both so I could see the status of files in explorer but get fully integrated features in the IDE (Right-click in solution explorer, histories, branching/merging, etc). It's possible Ankh requires Tortoise, I don't recall

Comment: Before you go down that route, why not try setting up a TFSPreview account/ it takes minutes and doesn't require any additional software or installation. The site's been up for over 2 years now IIRC and doesn't show any sign of going away soon. MS has also said that if it is ever to be taken down, they'll provide an upgrade path and a way to export your data/histories so no real downsides for a solo dev

Comment: I have used VSS 6.0 in the past for about 4 years and never has any issues with it but as now everyone recommends SVN so i am going to try it. Is it easy to set up?

Comment: is TFSPreview web based tool?

Comment: Both - There is a web UI which allows you to manage it but it integrat4s directly into VS in exactly the same way that you'd use a normal TFS Server. From the users point of view, about the only difference is you login to source control using a microsoft Live/Passport account